# Video stream camera IP with openCV - ERROR

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, ip, recording

I am trying to obtain the video from an IP camera but I obtain this message instead:

```
    WARNING: Couldn't read movie file 
"[http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/videostream.cgi?user=ADMIN&password=pass][1]"
```

I have imported all of the opencv's libraries to my project. My object "cap" has a valid value when I use: `VideoCapture cap(0);` But when I try this with HTTP, it's not working.

My code is:

```
VideoCapture cap("[http://IP_ADDRESS:PORT/videostream.cgi?user=ADMIN&password=pass][2]");

if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
{
    cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
    return -1;
}
else {
    cout << "OK" << endl;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just disable password and try again, I heard that  OpenCV does not support  password-protected  streams. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574554/stream-video-from-ffmpeg-and-capture-with-opencv

Comment: Haris, consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: Same error without password @Haris

Comment: Yo may need to disable pass word.

Comment: @Matthieu Pass dummy parameter as video extension like, `IpCam.open("http://IP:8080/?dummy=param.mjpg");`

Comment: I try all your recommandations but this is not working.