# OpenCV and RTMP

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, rtmp

I want to be able to create an application that can read and publish an RTMP stream.

Using OpenCV i could read rtp due to it's ffmpeg backend.

[Stream video from ffmpeg and capture with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574554/stream-video-from-ffmpeg-and-capture-with-opencv)

C++ RTMP is another possibility, but this is an RTMP server so it mainly requests and sends files. Although open source, i am unsure how to build or integrate this into a Visual Studio application in such a way as to make the function calls available to my project.

OTher sources indicate that OpenCV's RTSP isn't great.

http://workingwithcomputervision.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/issues-with-opencv-and-rtsp.html

How can you run a streaming server, such as RTMP C++ and get the raw data out. OpenCV can encode and decode image data for streaming, but how can you link the two?

Could a C++ application pipe a stream together? How could i interface with that stream to send it more images? Also, for receiving images?

Regards,

Comment: http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html

Comment: Here we seem to have a library that can read and publish rtmp. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cRMTPServer and LibRTMP works well.